# Why This Regex Matches With That Input (PCRE)?

Tags: regex, pcre

I cannot understand why would this pattern

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\.,-\?]+$
```

Will match with input such as follows:

```
should-match
should-match-2.no.problem.cool.with.me.
however:this->should;not;match=yet=it=does.
```

After all, `> : ; =` are not included in the pattern.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/76pc8aPHYp-8KAgB)

Comment: Without looking further into it - there is a suspicious unescaped minus in you character class.

Comment: @SebastianProske you are right!

Comment: Escape the `-` so that you have `^[A-Za-z0-9\.,\-\?]+$` and you do not need to escape `?` or `.` in a character class so now you have `^[A-Za-z0-9.,\-?]+$`

Comment: You can also put the hyphen immediately after a range: `^[A-Za-z0-9-.,?]+$`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are.  when you use `-` in a `[]` pattern you mean from character on the left to character on the right.  So `,-?`  actually means from ascii character `,` to ascii character `?`, which includes all characters in between.  This includes the ones you posted.

You can put the `-` at the end of the `[]` group and then it stands for itself, not meaning a range of characters, or you can escape it, by prepending a `\` char in front of it, as in `\-`.